# SQL create substring to display the min and max date as a date range separated by a delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have got this query (simplified from a detailed query) to return dates as a substring. I want to return a substring which has just the minimum and maximum of the date if more than 1 date else return just the one date.

This is my SQL query:

```sql
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING((SELECT distinct ','+ r.ENTRY  AS [text()] 
               FROM RESULT r 
               WHERE r.ENTRY IN ('19-09-2023', '20-09-2023', '21-09-2023', '22-09-2023') 
               AND r.sample_number = 74406
               FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 2, 1000) [Test Date]
```

This query returns:

```
19-09-2023,20-09-2023,21-09-2023,22-09-2023
```

However, I want just `19/09-22/09/2023` to be returned i.e. min to max date in the above format. If there is only one date then I just want that date returned.

How do I amend the query to get this? I do need it as a substring since this is just one of many other columns returned.

I tried to add a `CASE` expression to get the min and max when there are more than 1 `r.ENTRY`. That didn't work. I do not have any more ideas.

Thanks

Comment: What if the year is different between start and end dates? should the result be `19/12-11/02/2024` or should it be a different format `19/12/2023-11/02/2024`?

Comment: @Bohemian, good question, OP seems to be insisting on using bad date formats all over.

Comment: what if there are gaps between dates?

Comment: You are right, we can leave the year there so it covers the different years' scenario. Gaps between dates is not an issue. Just want to show that testing was done in that period.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in the minimum and maximum Date, you can use `MIN()` and `MAX()` together with `CASE` expression. No string aggregation is required

```
select case when min(ENTRY) <> max(ENTRY)
            then convert(varchar(10), min(ENTRY), 105)
            +    '-'
            +    convert(varchar(10), max(ENTRY), 105)
            else convert(varchar(10), min(ENTRY), 105)
            end
from   RESULT r
```

`CONVERT()` with style `105` will return string in `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for consecutive values of the `entry` column for a specific value of the `sample_number` column?

```
select @@version;

With
  result as (
    select *
    from (
      values
        (cast('20230919' as date), 74406),
        ('20230920', 74406),
        ('20230921', 74406),
        ('20230922', 74406),
        ('20230923', 74407),
        ('20230925', 74408),
        ('20230929', 74408)
    ) as t(entry, sample_number)
  ),
  t1 as (
    select
      *,
      dateadd(day,
              -dense_rank() over(partition by sample_number
                                 order by entry),
              entry) as gr
    from result
  )
select
  case
    when min(entry) = max(entry) then convert(nvarchar(10), min(entry), 103)
    else substring(convert(nvarchar(10), min(entry), 103), 1, 5) +
           '-' + convert(nvarchar(10), max(entry), 103)
  end as "Test Date"
  -- , sample_number
from t1
where
  sample_number = 74406 -- or 1 = 1
group by gr -- , sample_number;
```

Results:

```
+------------------+
|    Test Date     |
+------------------+
| 19/09-22/09/2023 |
+------------------+
```

[DB Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/203125).

Results for all rows of test data:

```
+------------------+---------------+
|    Test Date     | sample_number |
+------------------+---------------+
| 19/09-22/09/2023 |         74406 |
| 23/09/2023       |         74407 |
| 25/09/2023       |         74408 |
| 29/09/2023       |         74408 |
+------------------+---------------+
```

[DB Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/203124).

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more concise version of @Squirrel's excellent answer. You can use `CONCAT_WS`, which concatenates with a separator, and ignores nulls.

```sql
select
  concat_ws('-',
    min(r.ENTRY),
    case when min(r.ENTRY) <> max(r.ENTRY) then convert(varchar(10), max(r.ENTRY), 105) end
  ) as [Test Date]
from RESULT r;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the suggested code to work for me. My field is not a date field so I had to use the replace and convert function to convert it to date and then the minimum and maximum works correctly. My working code as below:

```
 `SELECT 
    SUBSTRING((SELECT distinct 
CASE when min(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),REPLACE(r.ENTRY,'-','/'),103)) = max(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),REPLACE(r.ENTRY,'-','/'),103)) THEN '-' + min(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),REPLACE(r.ENTRY,'-','/'),103)) ELSE
'-' + min(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),REPLACE(r.ENTRY,'-','/'),103)) + ' - ' + max(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),REPLACE(r.ENTRY,'-','/'),103)) END AS [text()] FROM RESULT r
               WHERE r.ENTRY IN ('19-09-2023', '20-09-2023', '21-09-2023', '22-09-2023') 
               AND r.sample_number = 74406
               FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 2, 1000) [Test Date]`
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**